# Optional "map" maps String to Boolean object instead of primitive boolean when using "var"

Tags: java, option-type

I have following problem, I'm not sure if it is IntelliJ Bug or something else.

I have static function which maps string to boolean. When I use this function in `Optional.map()` it maps every time to Boolean instead of boolean. Is this standard behavior of type inference?

```java
public class MyClass {

    public void myMethod() {
        Optional<String> myAttribute = Optional.of("1");
    
        final var myBoolean = myAttribute
          .map(MyClass::mapStringToBoolean) //it maps to Optional<Boolean>, why not to boolean when function gives primitive back?
          .orElse(false);

        // "myBoolean" is Boolean instead of boolean
    }

    public static boolean mapStringToBoolean(String myString) {
        return "1".equals(myString) || "true".equals(myString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Optional<T>#orElse` returns `T`, which cannot be a primitive. Try replacing `var` with `boolean` to force unboxing.

Answer (score 3):

As said by others, there is no `Optional<boolean>` as Java’s Generics do not support primitive types as type arguments.

However, you’re using the wrong tool for the job. Use

```java
final var myBoolean = myAttribute
    .filter(MyClass::mapStringToBoolean)
    .isPresent();
```

Answer (score 2):

Primitives cannot be used as generics in Java so you are getting autoboxed. Try to declare eg `List<int>` to see what will happen.